# Solar gravitational redshift problem

Tags: gravitational-redshift

At [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/gratim.html) the formula is:

$$ \frac{\nu_\infty}{\nu_0} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}} $$

I found this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00150581) in which the authors

> have studied the wavelengths of a large number of solar iron lines
>   observed near the center of the disk. They show that the observed
>   shifts (solar wavelength minus laboratory wavelength) for strong lines
>   agree with the predicted values given by

$$\Delta\lambda/\lambda = \frac{GM}{rc^2}= 2.12^{-6}$$

Can you please say if this formula is correct and where it comes from?

Also, if it is, I would imagine that the formula for the frequancy at infinity (or else) would be

$$\nu = \nu_{r_0}\left( 1-\frac{GM}{r_0 c^2}\right)$$

Can you tell me where I am wrong or why the official formula is different? Is that formula expressly mentioned in SR or is it derived in some way?

Comment: *I would imagine* That's not very useful to respond to.  You need to explain *why* you expect that form or we can't help you with any conceptual issue that may be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first formula is correct, it comes from the Schwarzschild metric and assumes that the Sun is a spherically symmetric mass. It compares the proper time of a stationary observer at infinity with the proper time of an observer at $r_0$.

Your third equation contains a transcription error, since you have missed the factor of two and the square root from the first equation?

The second equation is an *approximation* and arises if $r \gg 2GM/c^2$ and you do a binomial expansion of the first expression and then express the frequencies in terms of wavelength.

i.e.
$$ \frac{\nu_{\infty}}{\nu_0} =\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_{\infty}} \simeq 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2GM}{c^2r_0}\right)+ ...$$

and then 
$$\frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda_{\infty}} = 1-\frac{\lambda_0 }{\lambda_{\infty}} \simeq \frac{GM}{c^2r_0} $$

Comment: It's not a transcription error, if the formula were not approximated,   if GM/rc^2 is the exact value of the ratio between the decrease of frequency and the original photon, then the frequency of the photon at infinity $f_\infty$ is given by the original frequency f minus the ratio times the frequency = f - f * ratio = $f_{r_0}\times (1-\frac{GM}{r_0c^2})$

Comment: I really don't follow. $\nu$ is the frequency in your first formula. You literally multiply both sides by $\nu_0$ to get what should be your third formula.

Comment: I was just using f instead of nu. I didn't know that the second formula was an approximation.